# Why does google chrome not load this website in one go?

Tags: google-chrome, error-handling

I have created a website:

**www.ckmsalumni. com**

It does not open on one go in Google Chrome.

I get a bulk of errors in the developer's console:

```
ERR_CACHE_MISS

ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED ENCODING

ERR_CACHE_MISS
```

The funny thing is, I get these errors only on slow internet connections, whereas it loads fine without errors in a fast connection.

This makes the website load with half the files, thus ommitting many CSS and Javascript modules.

Reloading the website twice or thrice makes it load fine, which may be because of caching.

What is the real problem here?

Large files or bad code or slow connection?

I am willing to post codes here, but they are thousands of line with no specific part I can refer to.

Files in question:

```
www.ckmsalumni.com/index.php     
www.ckmsalumni.com/css/animate.min.css    
www.ckmsalumni.com/css/bootstrap.min.css    
www.ckmsalumni.com/css/ckmsjubilee.css
```

Answer (score 0):

I think This is an issue specific to Chrome, but there are two paths you can take to fix it,

1. check if you have the latest chrome version .
2. The error appears to be related to PHP sessions when sending response headers. 
   remove these response headers from your PHP script if possible

`header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: But I haven't added any headers in my PHP file.